# How to improve the performance of multiple joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a query with multiple joins in it.  When I execute the query it takes too long.  Can you please suggest me how to improve this query?

```
ALTER View [dbo].[customReport] 
As 
SELECT DISTINCT ViewUserInvoicerReport.Owner,      
    ViewUserAll.ParentID As Account , ViewContact.Company, 
    Payment.PostingDate, ViewInvoice.Charge, ViewInvoice.Tax, 
    PaymentProcessLog.InvoiceNumber  
FROM
    ViewContact 
    Inner Join ViewUserInvoicerReport on  ViewContact.UserID = ViewUserInvoicerReport.UserID 
    Inner Join ViewUserAll on  ViewUserInvoicerReport.UserID = ViewUserAll.UserID 
    Inner Join Payment on Payment.UserID = ViewUserAll.UserID 
    Inner Join ViewInvoice on Payment.UserID = ViewInvoice.UserID 
    Inner Join PaymentProcessLog on ViewInvoice.UserID = PaymentProcessLog.UserID
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

Work on removing the distinct.

THat is not a join issue. The problem is that ALL rows have to go into a temp table to find out which are double - if you analyze the query plan (programmers 101 - learn to use that fast) you will see that the join likely is not the big problem but the distinct is.

And IIRC that distinct is USELESS because all rows are unique anyway... not 100% sure, but the  field list seems to indicate.

Use distincts VERY rarely please ;)

Comment: Yakshemash, tomtom. Why do you tell us to use a distincts rarely ?

Comment: Because they are expensivbe. Now, most queries have distinct data. So, why make a REALLY epensive operation to make sure distinct data is distinct? Oh, you WANT to be slow? Well done.

Comment: Distinct checks all rows in the returning data. If there is no chance to get doubles - then why use it? Also, most of the time dubles woudl be an error in the query. And distinct is REALLY expensive - writes out all rows into a temporary table to unify them. Welcome to tempdb overload.

Comment: I agree about the use of `DISTINCT`. But this query (seems to me that) will not produce distinct results. The joins are all on `UserID` and not in primary keys. If there are for example, multiple payments with the same `PostingDate` for the same `UserID`, there will be duplicate rows.

Comment: Yes and no - in this case it may be nicer to make a distinct only on the relevan payments - but first validate that a user may make more than a payment entry per date.... you can definitely avoid the distinct on the full output and replact it with a join on a slect statement on Payment that is unique - no need to distinct everything.

Answer (score 0):

You should see the Query Execution Plan and optimize the query section by section.

The overall optimization process consists of two main steps:

1. Isolate long-running queries.
2. Identify the cause of long-running queries.

See - [How To: Optimize SQL Queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650689.aspx) for step by step instructions.

[image]

and

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to say how to improve the performance of a query without knowing things like how many rows of data are in each table, which columns are indexed, what performance you're looking for and which database you're using.

Most important:
1. Make sure that all columns used in joins are indexed
2. Make sure that the query execution plan indicates that you are using the indexes you expect